# How to test if turtles are dying mostly at a particular time of year?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, poisson-regression, circular-statistics, poisson-binomial-distribution

I have citizen science records of turtle sightings (alive/dead, and if dead what caused its death e.g. car/predator/etc), and the date they were spotted. What would be the most appropriate test to answer the following questions:

- are turtles are being killed mostly at a particular time of year (or month, if it is easier)?
- is the way turtles are killed related to time of year?

I have a lot more records of live than dead turtles, and the data of "causes of death" has lots of NAs, unfortunately. I am using R.

Answer (score 1):

Key here is that time of year is a circular scale. The dates of death could be converted to angles on the circle and their vector mean calculated as a summary resultant. With daily dates I tend to use a day of year variable $\text{doy}$ running from 1 to 365 to 366, and then calculate

$\sin[2 \pi ((\text{doy} - 0.5) / \text{number of days in year})] =: s$

$\cos[2 \pi ((\text{doy} - 0.5) / \text{number of days in year)}] =: c$

and the resultant as $\text{arctan} (\sum s / \sum c)$, converted back to a notional date. The vector mean can be supplemented by a measure of variability most commonly known as the mean resultant length, although several less commonly used names such as consistency are more evocative. Naturally you should plot the data too. Smoothing to get an estimate of the density function on the circle is often especially helpful.

A logit model of (alive, dead) as a response might be related to sine and cosine as predictors.

Accounts of circular statistics aimed at biologists include

Batschelet, E. 1981. *Circular statistics in biology.* 
London: Academic Press.

Zar, J.H. 2010. 
*Biostatistical analysis.* 
Upper Saddle River, New Jersey: Pearson Prentice Hall.

Despite its supposed updating, the text by Zar encapsulates a very old-fashioned style of statistics. For density estimation, see more readily

Fisher, N.I. 1993. *Statistical analysis of circular data.* 
Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

For R support, see Pewsey, A., M. Neuhäuser and G.D. Ruxton. 2013. 
*Circular statistics in R.* 
Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Answer (score -1):

To find out whether turtles are killed more in e.g. spring than at other times, you could do a t test. See `?t.test`.

This is assuming that your data has no selection bias - for example, that people go to the beach more at certain times of year, and spot turtles. A strong assumption!

To find out whether causes of death are related to seasons, you could use a chi-squared test - see `?chisq.test`.

Comment: For the t test what would you compare with what and how would you split the year without arbitrariness? For a chi-squared test, how would you subdivide the year without arbitrariness? The chi-squared test would even at best ignore the circular character of the data.

Comment: For this, you have to use your knowledge. You could test every month - or every week - but then you run into multiple testing problems. You could also do a simple regression and include e.g. month dummies. I don't think the circularity of the data is a problem for the chi-squared test - if you did a table of months versus deaths, it will still test the null that there's no relationship. (But I may be wrong about this!) A bigger issue may be the time-series nature of the data; you might want to look into time series methods. Sorry, I assumed you wanted something simple.

Comment: It's not that the circularity is a problem for chi-square: the point is that chi-square cannot use the information even on circular order. That is, shuffle spring, summer, autumn, winter (say) to any other order and the chi-square test result is the same, so information is lost. Otherwise I don't get a clear picture of what you are proposing. My suggestions use date information directly. Even if you are proposing separate t tests for each week or month, (1) how would that throw light on the question here? (2) what is the response variable and what are the two groups you are comparing?

Comment: Also, I am not the OP but @Claudia in asking about various models is not a newcomer to statistics.

Comment: FYI, I didn't downvote (and didn't get an upvote either!).